# Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object

Tags: websphere, db2-zos, websphere-traditional

i am trying to connect db2 from my java code in web sphere application server.
i am getting following exception.please suggest any one on this.

> Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl not a subtype] at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1232) at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookup(Helpers.java:925) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processBoundObjectForLookup(CNContextImpl.java:2877) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:3974) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1876) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1777) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1434) at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:616) at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165) at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179) at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428) at com.deere.u90.iaf.jdbc.connection.ConnectionManager.initializeEnvironment(ConnectionManager.java:276) ... 38 more Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl not a subtype at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newFactory(Unknown Source) at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.im.IMMetadata.setHistoryEventsFromHistoryXml(IMMetadata.java:745) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.im.IMMetadata.parseHistoryXmlFile(IMMetadata.java:587) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.im.IMMetadata.parseInstallRegistryFiles(IMMetadata.java:399) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.im.IMMetadata.(IMMetadata.java:269) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.im.IMMetadata.getIMMetadataInstance(IMMetadata.java:133) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.WASMetadata.parseMetadataFiles(WASMetadata.java:939) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.WASMetadata.(WASMetadata.java:784) at com.ibm.websphere.product.metadata.WASMetadata.getWASMetadataInstance(WASMetadata.java:215) at com.ibm.websphere.product.WASDirectory.initMetadataInstance(WASDirectory.java:1415) at com.ibm.websphere.product.WASDirectory.getIMLogLocation(WASDirectory.java:435) at com.ibm.websphere.product.VersionInfo.printSource(VersionInfo.java:1534) at com.ibm.websphere.product.VersionInfo.printReport(VersionInfo.java:1322) at com.ibm.websphere.product.VersionInfo.runReport(VersionInfo.java:1064) at com.ibm.websphere.product.VersionInfo.runReport(VersionInfo.java:1025) at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.ServerFunction$7.run(ServerFunction.java:596) at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.ServerFunction$7.run(ServerFunction.java:590) at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.ServerFunction.getServerVersion(ServerFunction.java:588) at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:748) at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CUtilityClass.createMCFEntry(J2CUtilityClass.java:468) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionFactoryBuilderServerImpl.createMCFandPM(ConnectionFactoryBuilderServerImpl.java:592) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionFactoryBuilderServerImpl.processObjectInstance(ConnectionFactoryBuilderServerImpl.java:1185) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ServerFunction.processObjectInstance(ServerFunction.java:2009) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionFactoryBuilderImpl.getObjectInstance(ConnectionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:662) at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.getObjectInstanceUsingObjectFactoryBuilders(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:349) at org.apache.aries.jndi.ObjectFactoryHelper.getObjectInstance(ObjectFactoryHelper.java:89) at org.apache.aries.jndi.OSGiObjectFactoryBuilder.getObjectInstance(OSGiObjectFactoryBuilder.java:62) at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:311) at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1122) ... 50 more

Comment: The problem might be that [you have an unsupported JDK version](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1059985). Further than that, I cannot help.

Comment: Thank @ken,Here am using IBM jdk8

Comment: Thanks @ken,Here am using IBM jdk8 with web sphere9

Comment: Any one can help on this?

Comment: I suspect the default XmlInputFactory has been redefined somehow, by use of a properties file or system property.  There's some info on how that might happen here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html  and in the file (was_home)/java/8.0/jre/lib/stax.properties.sample

Comment: @subbareddy Did you get any solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and here was my resolution 
I had wrongly spelled my jta data source in IBM Admin Console and was using a different name in my persistence xml so Websphere couldn't connect.
Please check the Resources Tab in the Admin Console and validate your jta data source name as declared in persistence xml